# I want to send multiple value pairs via API and insert them into SQL DB

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest, prepared-statement

So, what I'm trying to do here is I have a table which has the `product_id` and its `price` and I want to send these values via API and I'm not getting how to send it so that it can be inserted into DB. Can please someone help me with this? Actually I'm new to this and I've tried every possible solution that I know but no luck.
Recently I tried copying data from 1 table to another as the data to be inserted will be same as in other table because the data`(product_id, quantity, price)` to be inserted in is `order_items` table and I will copy the data`(product_id, quantity, price)` from `cart_items` as what the customer has in cart he will order that only.
This is the SQL query I'm trying to use here:

```
INSERT INTO order_items (product_id, quantity, price)
SELECT product_id,quantity,price FROM cart_items
WHERE cart_id IN (SELECT id FROM cart WHERE user_id=1 AND status='active');
```

Also, when I try to run this query it shows:

```
#1364 - Field 'order_id' doesn't have a default value
```

I think it is because I'm not passing any order_id value. If there is any way to pass it please let me know.
My approach might be incorrect as well so if anyone can help me out please I'm all ears.

These are my tables:

`cart`

```
    #   Name            Type    
    1   id              int(11)         
    2   user_id         int(11)         
    3   status          varchar(50) 
    4   item_count      int(11)         
    5   total           int(11)
```

`cart_items`

```
    #   Name         Type
    1   id           int(11)
    2   cart_id      int(11)
    3   product_id   int(11)    
    4   price        int(11)    
    5   quantity     int(11)
```

This `cart_id` is the `id` from cart table

`orders`

```
    #   Name        Type
    1   id          int(11)
    2   user_id     int(11)
    3   total       int(11)
    4   status      varchar(10)
    5   address_id  int(11)
    6   pay_method  varchar(10)
```

`order_items`

```
    #   Name        Type
    1   id          int(11)
    2   order_id    int(11)
    3   product_id  int(11)
    4   quantity    int(11)
    5   price       int(11)
```

This `order_id` is the `id` from orders table

Comment: Well I think you have to insert into `orders` table and then when you got ID of order you can insert into `order_items`.

Comment: Yes, I got that but how can I insert ```order_id``` into the table with the INSERT INTO..SELECT query? How can I merge the two queries,i.e., the query in the question and the query to insert ```order_id``` ?